# Regex to extract a particular pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am trying this for a long time but no help.

I have the following string:

> 42343473479|112273563||**ERROR|XYZ123|com.test.Test1||WebContainer : 
> 21|java.lang.NullPointerException** 
>       **at com.test.Test.compare(TestUtil.java:459)**
>       at com.test.compare(TestUtil.java:457)

Now I need a pattern to extract the following:

> ERROR|XYZ123|com.test.Test1||WebContainer : 21|java.lang.NullPointerException)
>   at com.test.Test.compare(TestUtil.java:459)

There could be any number

> :444)
>   :5723)

so far I:

> ERROR\|.*[^)]+)

But I need to match till ':459)' sort of pattern. There could be any number between : and ) at the end.

Please help.

**** Question Rephrased. Removed the portion to exclude text *****

Comment: What do you mean by exclude any text inbetween?

Comment: Did you try using `substring()` with `indexOf()`

Comment: I want to exclude any patten in between starting with \n and just before start of 'at '

Comment: Is `ERROR|XYZ123|com.test.Test1||WebContainer : 21|java.lang.NullPointerException)
at com.test.Test.compare(TestUtil.java:459)` an example of the full range of text you are trying to extract?

Comment: yes....thats correct....I want to extract the text as a whole.....

Answer (score 0):

You could try a regular expression in your java code like this:

```
(^.*)(ERROR.*\\n)(.*\\n)(.*\\n){2}(.*(\\n|$))*
```

You could use `replaceAll` with replacement of:

```
$2$3$4
```

Note this is answer is bearing in mind the fact that the question asked for a java regular expression, where the `\\` themselves must be escaped.

The unescaped version:

```
(^.*)(ERROR.*\n)(.*\n)(.*\n){2}(.*(\n|$))*
```

Comment: I am sorry...but the above expression is not working.

Comment: if we leave the excluding part and just consider from 'ERROR|' till ':123)'....how we should write the expression.

Comment: Where are you testing the expression and where in the sample text does it have ':123'?

Comment: As per the sample test we need to get the text till ':459)'. The number may vary.

Comment: The question is tagged as `java`, where each `\\` needs to be escaped with another `\\`, which is why each `\n` is shown as how java would accept it: `\\n`. However, in the the example linked above, it isn't directly using java and therefore it is enough to have a single `\\` by `\n`.